# not able to launch psql console

Tags: psql

New to psql getting the error while giving first command psql after installation. I checked all ports required are free and i changed service to "run" state ,still not working

FULL ERROR:

```
psql: could not connect to server:connection refused
     <0x0000274D/10061>
     Is the server runnining on "localhost"<::1> and 
     accepting
     TCP/IP connections omn port 5432?
could not connect to server:connectionrefused<0x0000274D/10061>
is the server running on host "localhost"<127.0.0.1> and accepting TCP/Ip connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you're using to connect?

Comment: just i foillwed the instruction given for windows in https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/optional_postgresql_installation/